# grep list each file once

Tags: command-line, search, grep

I'm looking some text in files , but three are a lot of files and searched text appears several times in one file, how can I receive a list of files that contains searched text with every file listed only once?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
grep -l xyz file*
```

where xyz is the search pattern , and file* is the list of files to be searched in

Answer (score 2):

`grep -l LIST PATTERN` is the way to go. Alternatively one could use `xargs` to do the same thing:

```
xargs grep "My Search Pattern"  < input.txt
```

`xargs` is particularly useful when you  would want to use `grep` on several filenames passed from a pipe, for instance:

```
find ~/Documents ~/bin -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'Search Term'
```